# Can I get original exchange response from CCXT API call?

Tags: python, api, binance, ccxt

Is there a possibility to get the original response from the exchange (e.g. Binance)?

Since CCXT offers the possibility to [overrride API params](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#overriding-unified-api-params), I thought it might be possible to get the original response as well.

Right now I'm overriding the CCXT module itself - maybe there is a better solution than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CCXT will store the most recent response in `exchange.last_http_response` (as a text string) and `exchange.last_json_response` (as a JSON-decoded object, if applicable). So, after executing a RESTful call, you can see the response in one or both of those properties:

```
import ccxt
from pprint import pprint
exchange = ccxt.binance()
ticker = exchange.fetch_ticker('BTC/USDT')
pprint(exchange.last_http_response)
pprint(exchange.last_json_response)
```

Apart from the above CCXT also serves the original structures returned from the exchange in the `info` field in all JSON objects returned from the [Unified CCXT API](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#unified-api).

Comment: I see now that `exchange.fetch_ticker` returns the original structure in the `info` field. However, `exchange.fetchOHLCV` doesn't have the info field. 

Can you give me a hint on how to get original data for streams, e.g. `watchOHLCV` as it returns a list?

Comment: @Josip you can do that with CCXT Pro like it is shown in this example: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/examples/ccxt.pro/py/intercept-original-ohlcv-updates.py